# Permalinks: Changing page names in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, permalinks

In wordpress, I'd like to know how to successfully change permalinks in my site from the ugly ?pageid4358454 to a custom name……which I'd assume I'd use **custom structure** for.

With this structure, I also want to know how to take a page of images (let's say, for a staff page), and make each one of those images clickable to a new page with BIO.

Much appreciated for your insights.

Comment: Have you not Googled your question? You can set permalink custom structure here: http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php if you click on the icon in the top right of the image you can add a custom link to any page

Comment: yes i've googled it…got a bunch of crap that didn't explain the solution….that's why i'm here.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin go to settings and go to permalinks and select name of post, then save the change.

Is all, is so easy.